# Issue while enable SSL in NopCommerce v3.80

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

I have been using nop commerce v3.80. 
They have provide an option to enable ssl in admin.
While enabling ssl in admin->store->enablessl option
I have been getting error like
**This page isn’t working. 
Redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS**
Even I tried redirection URL in web.config, but getting the same error. Can anyone suggest me to rectify this issue...!

Comment: Hope that you've SSL certificate installed on your server, and 
just set `SecuritySettings.ForceSslForAllPages` setting to `true`

Comment: Hi Div, I have also set true to SecuritySettings.ForceSslForAllPages. But still facing the same issue.

Comment: And what is store URL that you have set?

Comment: I have set the store url as  (http://)  http://subdomain.example.com into  (https://) https://subdomain.example.com.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i say because it may happen sometimes  do you set ssl certificate and bindg in iis?
...
And here is the solution, try to check Force ssl for all pages on settings,and then restsrt nopcommerce and your problem will solve.
If it doesn't work, try clear your browser cache and history or use incognito page, if the problem solved with incognito,it means your browser caches and histories should be clear.

Comment: Hi Amir, We have tried already as you said. But, still we have facing the same problem.

Comment: Go to settings, stores, select store and click edit
Set store url as url without https
Enable ssl 
Set store url with https in ssl url field which will apear after checking enable ssl
Then go to setting,general common, in security , check force ssl for all pages
Please send me your url if not works